Wideband Impedance Matching for Inductive Source/Load
I'm designing the frontend of a receiver and I want the output impedance to be 50Ω so that I can get as much power into the mixer. I tried placing a bandpass filter (image filter for 88-108MHz) in between the amplifier and the transformer primary side, but it didn't workout (signal became very noisy). The transformer has a 1:1 ratio and is used to isolate the amplifier from the mixer. I don't know where to place the filter and impedance matching network for 50Ω output impedance, passing 88-108MHz. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Schematic :

Edit :


Skipping the transformer/load, this stage obviously is not a power stage. Yet, on the right is a 50 Ohm termination, which tells me that this should be a power stage. That juxtaposition bothers me right away. And when you say it "became noisy" this says there was a before-this circuit. What is that circuit? Is it just this one without the 1:1 transformer and 50 Ohm load? Finally, noise matching would be critical in a non-power stage. What analysis did you do to match your input load to the conjugate noise impedance of the source (unshown?) I'm not good at RF and I'm out of questions.

Well, it might be a power stage accidentally, if the transistor's buit-in $C_{cb}$ and the parasitic $L_e$ in its package are providing the right voltage and current feedback. (Some transistors are popular for that property...) But most likely it is not (so you are right).

Well, 2SC3838K headlines a "11V, 50mA, 3.2GHz" rating, so the 12V supply is a bit marginal, but there's plenty of room to reduce the resistor values. Have you considered a matching network, other transformer ratio, loosely-coupled (double tuned) transformer, etc.? Please show the proceeding stage, and perhaps input network up to the antenna connection, as well.

A common base amp with a 3GHz transistor, without any measures against instability, is bold ;-). The input impedance is about 25 Ohm. The output impedance is high. There is no match unless you force the output to 50 Ohm with an appropriate collector shunt resistor and corresponding transformer ratio. Additionally, the current gain of the transistor is 1 so you hardly get any useful gain out of the amp. Maybe consider switching to a common emitter stage with shunt and series feedback for 50 Ohm In/Out.

The circuit before this was that but the transformer removed and RL is 5.2k. I used the common-base amp configuration since it does not suffer from Miller Effect, which is crucial at high frequencies. Although there is no current gain, there is lots of voltage gain (Rc / re). I'm trying to make a matching network that will pass 88-108MHz and matches 5.2k to 50. The full circuit is shown in the edit. I have not currently chosen which mixer I'm going to use, but looking at the options, it seems they all have 50 ohms input impedance.

Why do you think the output impedance is 5.2k? As you are not looking for GHz bandwidth and collector-base capacitance is very small in RF transistors, Miller is of no concern if you design a 50 Ohm common-emitter amp with appropriate voltage and current feedback. Yes, the common-base amp has voltage gain but after matching the collector load back down to 50 Ohm with a passive network, you loose most of that gain.

The output impedance is 5.2k because Rc is 5.2k. Could you give me a reference design of the amplifier you're talking about? Will this amp have 50 Ohm output impedance? That would require Rc to be 50 ohms, right?

The output impedance cannot be 5.2k because Rc is in series with 10uH and additionally the output impedance of the transistor is in parallel. Two examples of 50 Ohm CE-preamps are attached.

Take a look at the following two examples of common emitter, 50 Ohm I/O preamplifiers. The first one, with current and voltage feedback, is broadband, has medium gain and doesn't need much power.


The second example has high gain, uses inductive emitter degeneration for low noise and is I/O matched to 50 Ohm over the entire 88-108 MHz band.



Thank you. Where did you learn to design amplifiers like that? I've read "Art of Electronics" and they don't seem to teach it with inductors.

@TheButterMineCutter if you use DC feedback from the collector to the base you can more readily use an inductor for AC emitter degeneration. If you used a fixed bias on the base it becomes infeasible to use inductor emitter degeneration.

@TheButterMineCutter * AoE can not cover all types of amplifiers out there. More info about the principle and design of LNAs with emitter degeneration can be found for example in "Thomas H. Lee, Planar Microwave Engineering - A Practical Guide to Theory, Measurements and Circuits, 2004, Cambridge University Press" p.451.
